# What SAO spin-off had a female character that resembled Kirito?

Tags: sword-art-online

I know it was a *Sword Art Online* spin-off.

- There was Asuna and Silica in their SAO avatars.
- They meet a "Kirito".
- That "Kirito" turns out to be a female player.(like reverse of Kirito's GGO avatar)
- She is a fan of Kirito
- I think it takes place inside Aincrad in ALO and before Kirito transfer his ID to ALO again.

Anyone know the title of this spin-off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The spin-off you're looking for appears to be *Sword Art Online: Girls Ops*

This manga follows Leafa, Silica, and Lisbeth through a story that takes place both in the real world and in the new ALO<sup>[1](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_Art_Online_-_Girls_Ops_(manga))</sup>.

They do indeed meet a player that they first think is Kirito, but it turns out is a female player that dual wields out of admiration of Kirito. She says that she thinks fate made her character look like that.

From [Sword Art Online - Girls Ops Volume 01 Wikia](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_Art_Online_-_Girls_Ops_Volume_01):

> She then told the other girls that her name was Kuro and that she took her name from Kirito's nickname, «The Black Swordsman» (黒の剣士, Kuro no Kenshi?). Kuro then explained that she took up a dual-wielding style out of admiration of Kirito

[image: Girl Ops Cover 001]

Comment: Niiice~ thank you~ And how come Pina exist inside ALO ? or is it different dragon?

Comment: No problem. Your question isn't related so if you'd like to you can post a new question about that ^^